# How to acquire the background color and font color of output cells?

Tags: output-formatting, notebooks, color, cells, output

The following is how I grab the general colors used for an `EvaluationNotebook` but how does one target the colors to be used when creating an `OuputCell`?

```
fontcolor = 
  Extract[First[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor]], {2}];
background = 
  Extract[First[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], Background]], {2}]
```

Comment: You nees to pass a `CellObject` to `Options` instead, see e.g. `Cells` or `SelectedCells` for two ways how to get such objects

Comment: @LukasLang i am not looking for the colors of output cells already created. im looking for the setting of colors to be used when creating new output cells no different than those of say input cells.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question - how are you creating the output cell? Is it the one generated automatically by an evaluation, or are you using `CellPrint` or `NotebookWrite`?